# decision tree complexity and query complexity

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, query-complexity, decision-trees

I want good sources for starting with decision tree complexity and query complexity , what papers to start with ? what book chapters to read ? I already seen arora and barak book and I begin to read it ... so any other suggestions will be welcomed ...

Answer (score 3):

Chapters-3,4 in book [Analysis of Boolean Functions](http://analysisofbooleanfunctions.org/) by Ryan O'Donnell might be a good starting point.